# Javascript: Issue when using .click method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Firsty here is the html which corresponds with the code

```
<div class="grid_12">
    <ul id="categories">
        <li class="filter">Categories:</li>
        <li id="ny"><a href="#newYork" onclick="getImageCategories()"> New York</a></li>
        <li id="sc"><a href="#spanishCities" onclick="getImageCategories()">Spanish Cities</a></li>
        <li id="gv"><a href="#aGlasgowViewpoint" onclick="getImageCategories()">A Glasgow Viewpoint</a></li>
        <li id="sch"><a href="#someChurches" onclick="getImageCategories()">Some Churches</a></li>
        <li id="bh"><a href="#barcelonaHighlights" onclick="getImageCategories()">Barcelona Highlights</a></li>
        <li id="mp"><a href="#martin's Pictures" onclick="getImageCategories()">Martin’s Pictures</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- end .grid_12 - CATEGORIES -->
```

The idea here is that when each of these links are pressed a var id is changed to the correct number depending on which is clicked

Here is the code i have used to do this

```
if (nyView.click) {
    id = 1;
} else if (scView.click) {
    id = 2;
} else if (gvView.click) {
    id = 3;
} else if (schView.click) {
    id = 4;
} else if (bhView.click) {
    id = 5;
} else if (mpView.click) {
    id = 6;
}
```

the view vars are simply locators to find the correct div element so they are done like this

```
 nyView = document.getElementById('ny');
      scView = document.getElementById('sc');
      gvView = document.getElementById('gv');
      schView = document.getElementById('sch');
      bhView = document.getElementById('bh');
      mpView = document.getElementById('mp');
```

My issue is that no matter the element i clicked i only get the orginal... for me it seems like the code groups it all together so when u click the ny link it takes this as all other divs are clicked. This was tested as when i clicked the ny link innerHTML in all divs was executed... i am completely stuck as to why this is so would greatly appreciate the help

Comment: I don't see `getImageCategories()` in your JavaScript, but it's inline in your elements?

Comment: `onclick="getImageCategories(this)"` The element will be passed automatically.

Comment: this is the function name... i simply havent put in the code segment i posted

Comment: What do you expect the .click property to do? Because there is no such property on an HTMLElement...

Comment: i assumed it would take note when the particular element was clicked

Comment: this code works as it gives me a 1 as the id however when i click another it does not. It seems to only take the first if condition even if its wrong. Also why has this a -2?

Comment: Why is this tagged **jquery**?

Comment: Probably due to "lack of research". The [documentation for click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) is pretty good, I'm not sure what the confusion is...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan i have done research on this so i feel there is a large different between confused and lazy

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan there is click property on HTML element please check in console like var a = document.querySelectorAll('a')[0];
a.click.

Comment: @vinayakj ... which is a method, not a property, and would always be "truthy", which in the case of the code in the question, is pretty much useless.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan method cannot be a property!! howz so? I explained OP why his code was failing then how could be useless for code in question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need inline event handlers
2. You can use `event delegation`
3. Use `index` to get the clicked element index in `ul`

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid_12">
    <ul id="categories">
        <li class="filter">Categories:</li>
        <li id="ny"><a href="#newYork"> New York</a>
        </li>
        <li id="sc"><a href="#spanishCities">Spanish Cities</a>
        </li>
        <li id="gv"><a href="#aGlasgowViewpoint">A Glasgow Viewpoint</a>
        </li>
        <li id="sch"><a href="#someChurches">Some Churches</a>
        </li>
        <li id="bh"><a href="#barcelonaHighlights">Barcelona Highlights</a>
        </li>
        <li id="mp"><a href="#martin's Pictures">Martin’s Pictures</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var id;
$('#categories').on('click', 'li>a', function () {
    id = $(this).closest('li').index();
});
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/q9xbqck0/3/

Comment: @Tushar how to change the alert part to add to an actual variable?

Answer (score 0):

When you say `nyView.click` you are referring to the function definition and that would always be treated as `true` value, so you would get first condition always.

```
var id;
$('#categories').on('click', 'li', function(){
    id = this.id; // id = $(this).index();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach is very different, maybe someone else can work with your logic. I can't. My approach:

```
<div class="grid_12">
<ul id="categories">
    <li class="filter">Categories:</li>
    <li class="licategory" data-val="ny" data-id="1"><a href="#newYork" onclick="getImageCategories()"> New York</a></li>
    <li class="licategory" data-val="sc" data-id="1"><a href="#spanishCities" onclick="getImageCategories()">Spanish Cities</a></li>
    <li class="licategory" data-val="gv" data-id="1"><a href="#aGlasgowViewpoint" onclick="getImageCategories()">A Glasgow Viewpoint</a></li>
    <li class="licategory" data-val="sch data-id="1""><a href="#someChurches" onclick="getImageCategories()">Some Churches</a></li>
    <li class="licategory" data-val="bh" data-id="1"><a href="#barcelonaHighlights" onclick="getImageCategories()">Barcelona Highlights</a></li>
    <li class="licategory" data-val="mp" data-id="1"><a href="#martin's Pictures" onclick="getImageCategories()">Martin’s Pictures</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
$("li").on("click",function(){
    $("this").data("val");
    $("this").data("id");
})
```

Comment: i have used this method and havent got any success but thank you anyways. Apologies if my logic is hard to understand i do have little experience in this

Answer (score 0):

Add one common class like `.category`in all li and get the index()

```
$(".category").click(function(){
   // console.log(this.id);
    alert($(this).index())
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vb1szd8n/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

nyView.click returns a function that's why value of id =1 always no matter which link you clicked.....try this code

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function getImageCategories(element) {
                var nyView = document.getElementById('ny');
                 var     scView = document.getElementById('sc');
                 var     gvView = document.getElementById('gv');
                 var     schView = document.getElementById('sch');
                 var     bhView = document.getElementById('bh');
                 var     mpView = document.getElementById('mp');
                var id=0;



                if (element.parentNode === (nyView)) {
                    id = 1;
                } else if (element.parentNode===scView) {
                    id = 2;
                } else if (element.parentNode===gvView) {
                    id = 3;
                } else if (element.parentNode===schView) {
                    id = 4;
                } else if (element.parentNode===bhView) {
                    id = 5;
                } else if (element.parentNode===mpView) {
                    id = 6;
                }
                alert(id);

            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="grid_12">
    <ul id="categories">
        <li class="filter">Categories:</li>
        <li id="ny"><a href="#newYork" onclick="getImageCategories(this)"> New York</a></li>
        <li id="sc"><a href="#spanishCities" onclick="getImageCategories(this)">Spanish Cities</a></li>
        <li id="gv"><a href="#aGlasgowViewpoint" onclick="getImageCategories(this)">A Glasgow Viewpoint</a></li>
        <li id="sch"><a href="#someChurches" onclick="getImageCategories(this)">Some Churches</a></li>
        <li id="bh"><a href="#barcelonaHighlights" onclick="getImageCategories(this)">Barcelona Highlights</a></li>
        <li id="mp"><a href="#martin's Pictures" onclick="getImageCategories(this)">Martin’s Pictures</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```